# How to show $\sum_{m=0}^{d}(-1)^{m}{d\choose m}((x+m)^{d}-(x+1+m)^{d})=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How to show $\sum_{m=0}^{d}{(-1)}^{m}{d\choose m}((x+m)^{d}-(x+1+m)^{d})=0$

Comment: The title correction its $(-1)^{m}$  not $-1^{m}$

Comment: I think you can expand the whole expression, write it as a polynomial in $x$ and show that each coefficient is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $d$th forward difference operator applied to $\,x^d\,$ is defined by
$$ \Delta^dx^d :=\sum_{m=0}^{d}{(-1)}^{m}{d\choose m}(x+m)^{d}. \tag{1} $$
This is known to be equal to the constant function $\,d!\,$ This implies
that your summation expression is $\,d!-d!=0.$ The Wikipedia article
[Finite difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) has
some details but does not explicitly state the fact about $\,d!.$